# on item click runtime error in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android ,i am trying to create a view pager from a grid view but i have a problem while clicking on the item in the grid view.

here is my code

ImageAdapter.java

```
import com.netvariant.qareeboon.android.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

ImagePagerAdapter .java

```
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }
}


        // References to our images in res > drawable
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.bg_logo, R.drawable.three,
                R.drawable.four, R.drawable.two,
                R.drawable.one, R.drawable.btn_about,

        };

}
```

ImageViewPager .java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.netvariant.qareeboon.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewPager extends Activity {
    // Declare Variable
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the ViewPager
        setTitle("ViewPager");
        // Get the view from view_pager.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent p = getIntent();
        position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        // Retrieve all the images
        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Set the images into ViewPager
        ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
        // Show images following the position
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

the activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.view.View;

public class InfoGraphicActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the GridView
        setTitle("GridView");
        // Get the view from grid_view.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        // Set the images from ImageAdapter.java to GridView
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
       // ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        // Listening to GridView item click
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageViewPager.class);

                // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
                i.putExtra("id", position);

                // Start ImageViewPager
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    // Not using options menu for this tutorial
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.info_graphic, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

you can see error log below:

```
08-21 11:03:38.289: E/AndroidRuntime(5196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-21 11:03:38.289: E/AndroidRuntime(5196): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 

{com.netvariant.qareeboon.android/com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.ImageViewPager}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

08-21 11:03:38.289: E/AndroidRuntime(5196):     at com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.InfoGraphicActivity$1.onItemClick(InfoGraphicActivity.java:40)

08-21 11:03:38.289: E/AndroidRuntime(5196):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)

08-21 11:03:38.289: E/AndroidRuntime(5196):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1065)
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.netvariant.qareeboon.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.EducateActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_consult"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.ConsultActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_consult"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.ContactUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_us"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.InfoGraphicActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_info_graphic"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.qareeboon.android.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.SettingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.MyConsultation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_consultation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.ArticleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_article"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.Comments"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_comment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.AddComment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_comment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".ImageViewPager" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you declared your ImageViewPager activity in Android manifest.xml?

Comment: yes i did ... have a look at the manifest file please

Comment: declare the full path to the class in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this in logcat:

```
08-21 11:03:38.289: E/AndroidRuntime(5196): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 

{com.netvariant.qareeboon.android/com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.ImageViewPager}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You have not mentioned that activity in the `AndroidManifest` file of your application. Please do so.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.netvariant.android.qareeboon.ImageViewPager">
</activity>
```

Comment: no worries ... but i have another question .. do u have an idea on how to make the images zoomable in the view pager?

Comment: I suggest you to ask that as another question. And start another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your Activity in Manifest file please

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the new Activity in your manifest. Which ever Activity you are launching, its name needs to be added between your Application tags like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity_Class_Name" />
```

Comment: Remember to "Accept" an answer if your are happy with it so the post can be closed.

Comment: no worries ... but i have another question .. do u have an idea on how to make the images zoomable in the view pager?